# Julia: Controlling where cursor is in printed output

Tags: io, output, julia, ansi-escape

I found some cool things in a Julia package (ProgressMeter) that allows user to controller where the cursor is for printing out messages i.e.

```
print(io, "\u1b[1G")   # go to first column
print_with_color(color, io, s)
print(io, "\u1b[K")    # clear the rest of the line
```

What are these `"\u1b[1G"` pieces called, I am having trouble looking them in in the documentation. What other things are possible? Can I move cursor up 1 row?

EDIT:

I did some experiments:

```
### Without any unicode characters
julia> println("Hello First row"); print("hello "); print("Second row")
Hello First row
hello Second row

### \u1b[1A ### 
julia> println("Hello First row"); print("hello \u1b[1A"); print("Second row")
Hello Second row

### \u1b[1S
julia> println("Hello First row"); print("hello \u1b[1S"); print("Second row")
Hello First row
hello 
      Second row

### \u1b[1D
julia> println("Hello First row"); print("hello \u1b[1D"); print("Second row")
Hello First row
helloSecond row

### \u1b[1F
julia> println("Hello First row"); print("hello \u1b[1F"); print("Second row")
Second rowt row

### \u1b[1G
julia> println("Hello First row"); print("hello \u1b[1G"); print("Second row")
Hello First row
Second row
```

When I used `\u1b[1H` it took the cursor to the top of the console and `u1b[1J` took it to the top of console and cleared rest of console.

```
### \u1b[1K
julia> println("Hello First row"); print("hello \u1b[1K"); print("Second row")
Hello First row
      Second row
```

Comment: When trying this on a Mac in iTerm the control sequences does not seem to work. For example, when I try: ```julia --color=yes --eval 'println("Hello First row"); print("hello \u1b[1F"); print("Second row")'
Hello First row
hello Second row```it does not go up one row before printing the second one. Still, when I try ProgressMeter it behaves as expected. Any special setup needed?

Comment: I found a solution by using the cursor up ("\u1b[A") rather than line up ("\u1b[F") sequence. The latter is not ANSI.SYS so not supported everywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are all examples of [ANSI escape sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), which are a feature of terminal emulators, and are not specific to Julia.  The first character is `\u1b`, which specifies the unicode character at 0x1b (decimal 27, the key code sent for <kbd>ESC</kbd>, and often written as `\e`).  The sequence `\e[` is the "Control Sequence Initiator," or CSI.  You can see an incomplete list of escape sequences in the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CUU), including `A`, `D`, `F`, `G`, `K`, and `S`, as you have discovered.  The leading number modifies the command, often specifying a number of repeats.

Comment: Thanks! It was hard to search for what this was called.